# Optimization of bitwise AND of two arrays

Tags: c++, optimization, c++03

Seems like a simple question; I have to take the bitwise AND of two arrays, and return true if any two bits match, basically: `return ((dataArray & maskArray) != 0)`.

Of course, that's not legal C++. The present solution is akin to:

```
uint32_t dataArray[BIG_NUM] //Pretend it's initialized
uint32_t maskArray[BIG_NUM] //Pretend it's initialized
bool returnVal = false;

for(int i = 0; i < BIG_NUM; i++)
{
    if((dataArray[i] & maskArray[i]) != 0)
    {
        returnVal = true;
        break;
    }
}
return returnVal;
```

which, while functional, is neither able to be made parallel nor vectorized, and is thus painful, with 10% of CPU cycles being burned in this function. Any thoughts on how to clean it up?

edit: realized I shouldn't have the underlying member sizeof() as part of the array size.

Comment: Can you cache a parity value or checksum as a quick check for most cases?

Comment: `[BIG_NUM * sizeof(uint32_t)]` what are doing here?

Comment: @milleniumbug, not paying full attention to what I was typing, apparently; thanks for the catch.

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit machine? If so, and if possible, compile to use 64 bit integers. That should double your throughput.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk, I wish I were, though perhaps in the future. I suppose I could typecast to an array of size_t, then the function would recompile nicely if and when that migration happens.

Comment: As you have tagged your question explicitly with c++03: Does that mean, that you alsow have an old compiler?

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? How big is "BIG_NUM"? What compiler are you using? What type of machine are you running on?

Comment: Hi @MustafaOzturk (and MikeMB), VS2008 is the compiler, 32-bit Win7 is the target (for now), BIG_NUM really isn't all that large, maybe about 2,052. The nuisance is this function is called upwards of 2,000 times per second.

Comment: VS2008 pro? How many cores? You can multithread this thing using openmp in a few lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you typically return `false`, the following MIGHT be faster,:

```
bool res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < BIG_NUM; i++)
{
    res|= dataArray[i] & maskArray[i];      
}   
return res;
```

or even

```
bool res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < BIG_NUM; i++)
{
    resArray[i] = dataArray[i] & maskArray[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < BIG_NUM; i++)
{
    res |= resArray[i];
}
return res;
```

depending on your compiler

Comment: I'll give it a shot, didn't even think of accumulating results via an OR, but that makes a bunch of sense, and doesn't have the nasty habit of overflowing, either.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should help vectorize since it exits only multiples of 8 and has only single branching prediction per eight calculations(probably faster).

```
for(int i = 0; i < BIG_NUM; i+=8)
{
    uint32_t branch_once_per_8_calcs=0;
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+0] & maskArray[i+0];
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+1] & maskArray[i+1];
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+2] & maskArray[i+2];
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+3] & maskArray[i+3];
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+4] & maskArray[i+4];
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+5] & maskArray[i+5];
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+6] & maskArray[i+6];
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=dataArray[i+7] & maskArray[i+7];
    if(branch_once_per_8_calcs!= 0)
    {
        returnVal = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

also you can increase step size to 64 or 128 and check once at the end of each step using nested loops so could get even faster.

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < BIG_NUM; i+=8)
{
    uint32_t branch_once_per_8_calcs=0;
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=(dataArray[i+0] & maskArray[i+0]) | (dataArray[i+1] & maskArray[i+1]);
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=(dataArray[i+2] & maskArray[i+2]) | (dataArray[i+3] & maskArray[i+3]);
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=(dataArray[i+4] & maskArray[i+4]) | (dataArray[i+5] & maskArray[i+5]);
    branch_once_per_8_calcs+=(dataArray[i+6] & maskArray[i+6]) | (dataArray[i+7] & maskArray[i+7]);
    if(branch_once_per_8_calcs!= 0)
    {
        returnVal = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

using less adds and assignments. Dont forget to check for overflows which can cause false negatives.

Comment: If you replace adds with ors you won't need any overflow checks.